# Best way to use java sql connection

Tags: java, sql, connection

What is the best way to use connection in java application that having around 100 classes.
1) When user logging to the system, create a connection and pass to other classes and close when user presses exit button. or,
2) create a connection within every method and close when method ends.(Methods like we use for get data from db)

Answer (score 2):

The standard answer is to use connection pooling which often strikes the right balance between having too many connections and having as many connections as you need for concurrency. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/ConnectionPoolDataSource.html

Answer (score 0):

As always it depends.  You can't legitimately have millions of connections open to a database in 2013, this is a performance issue.  What you want to do is cache as much of the data as possible to reduce round trips to the database.  Typically you only want a connection open when it is being used, no need to have phantom connections open.