# Best way to use an SQL connection in Java

Tags: java, sql

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421070/best-way-to-use-java-sql-connection) one, but more specific.

I have multiple classes that execute queries against the same database. The problem is that the host may occasionally experience problems with the Internet connection, and my application must be designed against that knowledge.

So I cannot just create `java.sql.Connection` once, because it can break at any time. If a connection breaks while executing one of the queries - it's OK for me. The easiest way is to just create a new one in each query method:

```java
public static Profile getProfileBySteamID(long userid) {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Globals.dbConnection);
         Statement st = connection.createStatement()) {
        final ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT " +
                                              "p_id, p_name, p_id_dis, p_uid, " +
                                              "p_lastupd, p_lastservertime, p_roles " +
                                              "FROM profiles WHERE p_uid='" + userid + "'");
        if (!res.next())
            throw new RuntimeException("No such profile");
        long disID = res.getLong("p_id_dis");
        String steamid = res.getString("p_uid");
        return new Profile(steamid, disID);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public static Profile getProfileByDisID(long userid) {
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Globals.dbConnection);
         Statement st = connection.createStatement()) {
        final ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT " +
                                              "p_id, p_name, p_id_dis, p_uid, " +
                                              "p_lastupd, p_lastservertime, p_roles " +
                                              "FROM profiles WHERE p_id_dis='" + userid + "'");
        if (!res.next())
            throw new RuntimeException("No such profile");
        long disID = res.getLong("p_id_dis");
        String steamid = res.getString("p_uid");
        return new Profile(steamid, disID);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

// ... and about 7 more methods like these
```

I'm OK with the possible performance issues (because these queries are executed not so frequently), but this is too much repeated code that is hard to extract to other private methods, and, you know, kinda looks ugly.

So my question is how to get that `java.sql.Statement` (or better - `PreparedStatement`) in as short expression as possible, and without the try-catch statements if possible. Maybe I should consider using `ConnectionPool`?

I'd like to get some examples of the solution, or links to source code examples of `ConnectionPool` with `PreparedStatements` usage or anything similar

Comment: Use this. https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Answer (score 0):

Write a helper method which does the common code:

```
public class DBHelper {
    public interface SqlFunction<T> {
        T apply(Statement statement) throws SQLException;
    }
    public static <T> T withStatement(SqlFunction<T> task) {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(Globals.dbConnection);
             Statement st = connection.createStatement()) {
            return task.apply(st);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Profile p = DBHelper.withStatement(st -> {
            final ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT " +
                    "p_id, p_name, p_id_dis, p_uid, " +
                    "p_lastupd, p_lastservertime, p_roles " +
                    "FROM profiles WHERE p_id_dis='" + userid + "'");
            if (!res.next())
                throw new RuntimeException("No such profile");
            long disID = res.getLong("p_id_dis");
            String steamid = res.getString("p_uid");
            return new Profile(steamid, disID);
        });
    }
}
```

By the way, you should be using `PreparedStatement` -- it handles escaping parameters, so it is both easier to use and safer against malicious SQL injection.

Using a connection pool, e.g. Hikari, is also a good idea in addition to the approach I suggest above. It will handle broken connections and reduce the overhead of making new connections. It will also allow you to limit the number of concurrent connections your application will use.